# Screensaver to display random Line2D.Double every second (JPanel inside JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, java-2d

I'm trying to create a screensaver that displays a new random line every second. It's built inside a JPanel embedded inside a JFrame.

The problem is that every time the random line is built, it's touching the edge of the JFrame. I have it set up so that the line is always within the JPanel, but I don't want it touching the edge of the JFrame every time.

It never displays any lines in the middle of the frame. I'm sure there's a simple fix. I'm just looking for a fresh set of eyes. I'm probably not understanding the coordinate system correctly, Thanks.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScreenSaver extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    Timer timer;
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;

public ScreenSaver() {
    timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    timer.start();
}

    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    repaint();
}

public void GetRandomValues(){

    Random randh = new Random();
    Random randw = new Random();

    // get width of JPanel
    int w = getWidth();

    // get height of JPanel
    int h = getHeight();

     x1 = randh.nextInt(h);
     x2 = randh.nextInt(h);
     y1 = randw.nextInt(w);
     x2 = randw.nextInt(w);

}

    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

   super.paintComponent(g);

   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   GetRandomValues();

   g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
}

 public static void main (String[] args){

    ScreenSaver s1 = new ScreenSaver();        

    // jf is the JFrame
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setTitle("ScreenSaver.java");
    jf.setSize(800, 500);
    // puts frame in middle?
    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    // panel inside frame
    jf.add(s1);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single `Random` object, initialize it once, do not reallocate it on every timer. Also, there is a mixup in coordinate creation. It should be:

```
private Random random = new Random();

public void GetRandomValues(){
    // get width of JPanel
    int w = getWidth();

    // get height of JPanel
    int h = getHeight();

    x1 = random.nextInt(w);
    x2 = random.nextInt(w);
    y1 = random.nextInt(h);
    x2 = random.nextInt(h);
}
```

The `x` coordinates should be constrained by the width, and `y` coordinates by height. You had it the other way.

Comment: haha you know what the real culprit was? i was changing x2 twice. i should have changed y2 after y1, instead i changed x2 again. wow. thanks for pointing that out though. i would have never noticed what i did!

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza yes, I thought I messed it up in my local copy, so I fixed it, but it is also in your original code :) I am glad it worked out :)